# rake assets:precompile gives no erros but mina deploy fails on running the same command

Tags: css, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, mina

I have a rails 4 app that I'm trying to deploy with mina. When I run `mina deploy` it fails on the asset precompiling step and exits with a status 19. This is the error that it's spitting out:

```
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                  
Invalid CSS after " *": expected "{", was "= require found..."                                                                                                                 
(in /var/www/someapp/tmp/build-139204594512190/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)                                                                                      
(sass):15
```

So I can see that clearly something may be wrong with the css file and the attempted precompiling of it. I wanted to make sure that something was wrong with the file before I went in to try and fix things and so I ran `rake assets:precompile`. Lo and behold no errors, everything goes along fine. I figure maybe it's a difference between how dev is configured compared to production so I backed up my development.rb file, copied the production.rb and renamed it as development.rb and tried again and it worked. So if I run the command from rake it works but if mina tries the command during the deploy it fails.

I really don't know how how to approach this. Below is the application.css file, the line that's giving an error is `*= require foundation_and_overrides`

```
/*                                                                                                    * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files                                                                                 
 * listed below.                                                                                                                                                                      
 *                                                                                                                                                                                    
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,                                                                                    
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.                                                                                     
 *                                                                                                                                                                                    
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the                                                                                       
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.                                                                                                     
 *                                                                                                                                                                                    
 *= require_self                                                                                                                                                                      
 *= require_tree .                                                                                                                                                                    
 */                                                                                                                                                                                   
 *= require foundation_and_overrides                                                                                                                                                  

 @font-face     {                                                                                                                                                                         
    font-family: 'relay-medium';                                                                                                                                                  
    src:  url('<%= asset_path("relay-medium.ttf") %>');                                                                                                                           
    font-weight: normal;                                                                                                                                                          
    font-style: normal;                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: So I just noticed that my last require it outside the comments...once I moved it back in the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

And the problem is fixed by moving the last `*= require foundation_and_overrides` into the comment block.